# Unidirectional Many To One mapping with cascade

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Is it possible to map the following with GORM?

I want to get rid off all associated events when I delete a person.

Person object should not have a link to events.( I want to avoid using `hasMany` on Person domain)

```
class Person {
    String username
}

class Event {
    String description
    static belongsTo = [person:Person]
}
```

I'm getting now a 'Referential integrity constraint violation' when doing `person.delete()` because events are not removed before deleting person.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that is possible without using `hasMany` (speaking of which, why do you want to avoid that anyway?)

[This SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715146/how-to-define-an-inverse-cascade-delete-on-a-many-to-one-mapping-in-hibernate) states:

> Hibernate only cascades along the defined associations. If A knows
>   nothing about Bs, nothing you do with A will affect Bs.

Use `static hasMany` and bam, problem fixed.

**Edit:**

The only way I think you could achieve this is using `beforeDelete` on the `Person` class to delete all the associated `Event`s, i.e.

```
class Person {
    def beforeDelete() {
        def events = Event.findAllByPerson(this)
        for (e in events) {
            e.delete()
        }
    }
}
```

See [the documentation on Events and Auto Timestamping](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.7/guide/GORM.html#advancedGORMFeatures) for more info on that.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I'm going to have a lot of domain objects in my app that have to be associated with a Person. I thought that I could avoid to modify the hasMany modifier in Person class each time I do new association. I don't really need bidirectionality but I see it will save me a lot of trouble.

Comment: Understandable! The second option might be worth giving a shot. Unfortunately either way the `Person` class is going to end up knowing about the `Event` class.

Comment: So I think I'll get with bidirectional association. What seems unnatural to me now is that I cannot simply do a `new Event(person:somePerson).save()` `Person.get(somePerson.id).events` will be null :( Do I always have to add the Event through Person?

Comment: I think you will have to do a `Person.get(params.id).addToEvents(new Event())`

Answer (score 0):

The above will not work

Why not define a no reference mapping:

```
class Person {
    String username
    static hasMany=[Events]
}
```

This way there is no actual bindings of events to person but a person can have many events